# VS 2010 Deployment project remove Welcome dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, project

How to remove Welcome dialog? When I delete it from user interface menu i get error: Unable to build dialog module group named 'Start'. Is it possible to skip this dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I`ve found a solution. Using Orca tool delete all occurrences of WelcomeForm in tables.